# Prove that $n$ is even.

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $n$ is even

$$\left(\dfrac {\cos A + \cos B}{\sin A-\sin B}\right)^n + \left(\dfrac {\sin A+\sin B}{\cos A- \cos B}\right)^n = 2\cot^n \left(\dfrac {A-B}{2}\right)$$

Please help. I didn't get any idea regarding this.

Comment: Do you mean that if $n$ is even, you want to prove the identity?

Comment: @ m-agag 2016,  It is required to prove that $n$ is even..

Comment: I think he means to use the given equality to show that $n$ is even.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are any numbers which make the identity sense?

Comment: @ m-agag 2016,  $\A $ and $\B $ are angles in degrees

Comment: degree can be changed into radians.

Comment: @ m-agag 2016,  I couldn't understand what you mean to say??

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac {\cos A + \cos B}{\sin A-\sin B} = - \,\dfrac {\sin A+\sin B}{\cos A- \cos B} = \cot \left(\dfrac {A-B}{2}\right)$$

Comment: @ dxiv,  what is this?  How does it complete the proof?  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois First, prove the above using the usual trigonometric identities. Then, $a=-b=c$ and you know that $a^n+b^n=2c^n$ $\iff$ $a^n+(-a)^{n}=2a^n\,$, which should tell you something about $n$.

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.

Answer (score 1):

Or, even simplier, one could just choose any value for $A$, and $B$; then use the equality given to deduce that $n$ must be even, like this:

By substituting $A = 0$; and $B = \frac{\pi}{2}$; we'll arrive at:
$$\underbrace{(-1)^n}_{\text{swap this one to the other side}} + \underbrace{1^n}_{\text{this is }1} = 2\times(-1)^n$$
Changing sides will yield:
$$1 = (-1)^n$$

Which means that **if** the equality holds for all $A$, and $B$, **then** we must have $n$ is even.